# Spring Boot annotation attribute overriding doesn't work on beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a custom annotation for enabling functionality based on feature flags. I'm basing my approach on the `ConditionalOnProperty` annotation, but to enable code reuse I want to define a common prefix that can be used wherever I need this functionality.

I have defined my annotation as below.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Documented
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "foo.bar")
public @interface ConditionalOnFeature {
    @AliasFor(annotation = ConditionalOnProperty.class, attribute = "value")
    String[] value();
}
```

I'm using the `AliasFor` annotation to set the `value` attribute in the `ConditionalOnProperty` annotation, and hardcoding my prefix as `foo.bar` (all my features will sit under this property). As far as I understand [Spring annotation overriding](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Annotation-Programming-Model#attribute-aliases-and-overrides), this should work.

However when I use this on a class (for example a controller), the code fails to compile, stating that `The name or value attribute of @ConditionalOnProperty must be specified`.

```
@RestController
@ConditionalOnFeature("enable-fancy-controller")
public class FancyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fancy-method", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String fancyMethod() {
        return "Fancy";
    }
}
```

However it works perfectly fine when I instead use my annotation on a method. Compiles successfully and behaves as intended.

```
@RestController
public class FancierController {

    @ConditionalOnFeature("enable-fancier-method")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/fancier-method", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String fancierMethod() {
        return "Fancier";
    }
}
```

Have I configured my annotation wrong? Or is this some bug with Spring?